# Novel about a spacefaring mission trying to reestablish contact with Earth

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a novel I read in the early 90s; it came from a local library so it may be quite a bit older.  Might've been a YA novel, as it was in the same shelf as a bunch of William Sleator novels.  All my memory detailed below.

- A spacefaring civilization sends a mission to re-establish contact and possible trade with Earth; they had been in the first stages when WW3 or some other apocalypse began.
- The leader of the mission is a younger woman, humanoid, remember something green about her but can't remember what exactly (hair, skin, or eyes, not sure).  Her core team she picks out is small, maybe 3 or 4 people like a tech specialist, a doctor, and a psych/socio specialist.  They are assigned a full cruiser ship as support.
- They find Earth has largely recovered but is covered by a lot of wilderness.  Humanity is around but what's left is at some tribal, some pre-industrial levels, with very few big cities.
- They establish contact with one of the bigger centers, basically by dropping their shuttle in town square and opening the door, waiting for someone to walk in.  The town had apparently studied or worked out that aliens had landed in the past, and worked out a rough first contact protocol if someone landed.  I think the logic was to show non-aggression but also determine if the landers had hostile intent as soon as possible.  So their rep played canary and walked right into their ship, nude with arms open so he could hide no weapons.  He was then blushing when the Green woman unexpectedly returned the gesture in kind.
- A bit of time passes as contact develops.  Green woman isn't getting much support from the cruiser, so she requests a bunch of ground bases to be built to keep their crew busy and make them useful.  The mission starts making contact with more villages, finding most of them have an odd legend about a savior of humanity, and without fail all of them have a radio of some sort that this savior is supposed to call them on.  I think the savior is supposed to be called Lee Lukari, but I may have the name misspelled.
- The team collects a great many of the radios (but not nearly all).  They are quite surprised when they all turn on and start requesting a call back so Lee can save humanity.  The signal turns out to be from an alien ship on rapid approach.  Their own cruiser bugs out because they got caught flatfooted and don't recognize them, claiming a first contact / unknown hostiles regulation that mandates they retreat and analyze.  Core team is left on their own with a bunch of half-built bases.  The bases still have shuttles, supplies, bits of tech.  The biggest thing they have is nigh-invincible energy shields, around each of the bases, but they also have a few personal units too.
- The aliens had arranged the radios for easy collecting of humans, so they can enslave them for use in some sort of farm.  The animal they were farming was really odd, and Earth is ideal for it apparently.  Strongly implied they pulled strings to cause the fall of man in the first place.
- The animal they farm is constantly producing this fibrous grey trunk of a cable.  When the good guys get a bit of it they figure out how to separate the fibers; trying things they weave some into cloth.  Something about the fabric produces a pleasure effect on skin, and it's actually directly compared to a drug.  They presume the aliens are selling it elsewhere as an exotic narcotic.
- Aliens set up their farms, guerrilla war and much sneakiness ensues.  One of the first bits of sabotage found is feeding the animals a particular Earth plant (dandelions, I think) to upset their production - they get diarrhea instead of wonder fabric.
- My brain wants to say the aliens started to be called Unks (short for Unknowns?) but the second thing my brain says is this is ridiculous so I don't know how helpful that is.
- I know there's a bit of relationship juggling in the good guys, but I really don't remember who
- The alien mothership is brought down by the Green woman sneaking onboard, using her personal shield to protect herself, and shouting that Lee Lukari (again, sp?) is having her vengeance.  She finds a control center and sets the orbital path to start kissing mountains.  As the ship comes down, she can't find the hatch back out.  She only barely survives the crash due to the shield tech.
- After some time healing, the "reinforcements" finally arrive, a full combat fleet.  Since the ship is downed and the only aliens left are now hiding in caves, they don't have much to do but try to assume command.  Annoyed at their antics, she sets herself up as leader of Earth, knowing they can't do much to object since they have a potential war to fight.  I think she also offers the wonder fabric they can now produce as a trade item to get the technology to rebuild Earth civilization on a large scale.  Manipulating the command into doing what is essentially a space parade (looks like a bunch of moving stars from the ground), she's able to pass off the fleet as her own and convince the remaining aliens to surrender as well.
- I want to say that the cover was colored yellow and green, but I don't remember what it was depicting and don't remember how reliable my memory is here

I have repeatedly tried to investigate the works of Melissa Scott (as suggested by @mkennedy) and found no matches in the plot summaries I can find online.  It is possible I'm missing one or more of her works, but there doesn't seem to be a large amount of her books that fit the timeframe.

Comment: Am not sure what this book is, but are now intensely curious about it!

Comment: Is there any more info you can think of, such as names of characters, the race of aliens were called etc?

Comment: Some detail sound like a mangled version of Melissa Scott's Empress of Earth (Does the name Silence Leigh sound familiar?) but it's likely just similar tropes.

Comment: @mkennedy - Nope, not it, no magus in this book I'm certain, but that actually looks interesting now

Comment: @Josh - dredging more details but I'm really not getting any names.  Edited in.

Comment: Do you remember what language you've read this in?

Comment: @b_jonas - This was in English.  Came out of a high school library in New York.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a very long shot, but I wonder if this might be [Alien Main](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?2017) by T. L. Sherred.

This seems a very obscure book and I can find only the very briefest descriptions of it. I mention it only because it is the sequel to [Alien Island](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9684), which I have, and that book does contain a main character called Lee Lukkari. It's possible that this character got reused for the sequel.

The only descriptions of the book I can find are tantalisingly vague but consistent with your description. For example [Google Books says](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Alien_Main.html?id=L6JAPgAACAAJ):

> Fifty years after the nearly total annihilation of Earth by war and disease, three agents of the galactic federation set out to reopen contact with the closed world and reestablish trade with the planet's shattered civilization

and [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._L._Sherred):

> Set on Earth some two hundred years after aliens had nearly destroyed life on the planet, the novel finds descendants of the aliens returning to atone for the atrocities committed by their ancestors. They find that the inhabitants of Earth are now living in tribes, with no connections except for a common belief in a goddess, whose return they await.

The time frame fits since the book was published in 1985, and the cover is yellow and green (ish):

[image: Alien Main]

I wouldn't normally post an answer based on such slender evidence, but I post it in the hope that one of the site members has or can find a copy of the book and maybe confirm the identification.

Comment: Looks very very promising, although the cover isn't immediately clinching it. Have an upvote and I'll let you know once I'm more awake.

Comment: The more I'm digging the more certain I am that you've got it, even a user review on amazon lines up with the details, but like you said, this is pretty obscure.  No ebook copies available through the publisher, any stores, or gutenberg (or even less legit sources), probably was never published that way; no copies I can find in local library systems or used book stores.  It's terribly terribly unlikely for that character name to just pop up out of nowhere though.

Comment: @Radhi: If you're really desperate to track it down, you could try searching [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/alien-main/oclc/11677428) for your location and seeing if there's a copy in a reasonable distance.

Comment: Also, [this Goodreads description of *Alien Main*](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/912626588?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1) is consistent with the description given.

Comment: ... and this [New York Times review of the book](http://www.nytimes.com/1985/09/08/books/science-fiction.html?scp=2&sq=sherred%20alien%20main&st=cse&pagewanted=2) (at the end of the column.)  "Why, for example, do the scattered human tribes, which have no contact with one another, all venerate the same protective goddess, and why do they all possess the same mechanical icon that they believe the goddess will one day use to announce her second coming?"

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - mostly I just want to verify the find - I'd have some interest in acquiring and re-reading it as well (if only to prove it wasn't a product of a fever or warped teenage brain) but I already have plenty of things I'm never going to have time for already, so I was hoping it'd be easier.  WorldCat was a very good suggestion, and there is one nearby copy, but only in a university depository, which I will not be able to access.  You're right though, everything checks near perfectly.

Comment: Wow, I never heard of this, and those are 2 authors that I admire very much. I had no idea that Sherred was still writing in the 1980s.  I wonder if there is any way to acquire this.

Comment: @Radhil There are several copies on abebooks for less than $10.

Comment: @OrganicMarble:  According to Wikipedia, Sherred had a mild stroke in 1971 and stopped writing at that time.  *Alien Main* was unfinished at the time of Sherred's death in 1985, and Biggle completed it (hence the co-authorship.)